# Use Fourier series to show $\cos(x)=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n \sin(2n x)}{4n^2-1}$ on $(0,\pi)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-analysis

There's a theorem on my book which is stated as follows:

if $f(x)=f(-x)$ when $(0,\pi)$, then $$f(x)\sim a_0/2+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \cos(nx)$$ where 
$$a_n=2/\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}f(t)\cos(nt)dt$$

My solution is to consider $\cos(x)$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$ and then use the theorem directly.

But if I calculate $a_1=2/\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^2(t)dt=1 \neq 0$ so I must have a $\cos(x)$ in my series, should I consider an odd extension??

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need an extension; just consider $\cos x$ on $[0,\pi]$ directly. Then

$$
\int_0^\pi\cos x\cos2nx=0\;,
$$

and you obtain the desired result by evaluating the sine coefficients using

$$
\int_0^\pi\cos x\sin2nx=0\;.
$$

Comment: But $\int_{0}^{\pi}cos(x)cos(1x)dx  \neq 0$

Comment: @Euler'slittlehelper: Sorry, I forgot to write the factor of $2$ in the frequencies. $1$ doesn't occur as a frequency in a Fourier series over the fundamental domain $[0,\pi]$; the frequencies are $2n$.

Comment: Why should I integrate $\int_{0}^{\pi}cosxcos2nx dx$ not $\int_{0}^{\pi}cosxcosnx dx$

Comment: @Euler'slittlehelper: Because that's how the Fourier series is defined. The frequencies are $\frac{2\pi n}L$, and here the length $L$ of the fundamental domain is $\pi$.

Comment: But cos(x) is $2\pi$ periodic, so the L should be $2\pi$?

Comment: @Euler'slittlehelper: I suggest that you look at [the definition of the Fourier series at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition) (where they use $P$ for the length I denoted by $L$). It seems you're thinking of a Fourier series with fundamental domain of length $2\pi$ as some kind of standard – that's just one particularly common example.